# How does debuggers/exceptions work on a compiled program?

Tags: debugging, exception, compilation, cpu-architecture

A debugger makes perfect sense when you're talking about an interpreted program because instructions always pass through the interpreter for verification before execution. But how does a debugger for a compiled application work? If the instructions are already layed out in memory and run, how can I be notified that a 'breakpoint' has been reached, or that an 'exception' has occurred?

Comment: When setting a breakpoint you actually write a special opcode `int3` into a given position in the code, that will tell the execution to halt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of hardware and/or the operating system.

Most modern CPUs have several debug registers that can be set to trigger a CPU exception when a certain address is reached. They often also support address watchpoints, which trigger exceptions when the application reads from or writes to a specified address or address range, and single-stepping, which causes a process to execute a single instruction and throw an exception. These exceptions can be caught by a debugger attached to the program (see below).

Alternatively, some debuggers create breakpoints by temporarily replacing the instruction at the breakpoint with an interrupt or trap instruction (thereby also causing the program to raise a CPU exception). Once the breakpoint is hit, the debugger replaces it with the original instruction and single-steps the CPU past that instruction so that the program behaves normally.

As far as exceptions go, that depends on the system you're working on. On UNIX systems, debuggers generally use the [`ptrace()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) system call to attach to a process and get a first shot at handling its signals.

**TL;DR** - low-level magic.

Comment: That's awesome. Didn't know that was a processor feature.